# What age was Ted Allpress when he played in Thor?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, thor

What was the age of the actor that played the young version of Loki in the first Thor movie? I'm just trying to figure about what age young Thor and Loki were meant to be and i'm not good at  guessing.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this site](http://www.vivienneclore.com/artiste/ted-allpress/):

> Ted, made his professional stage debut at the age of 9 in The Donmar Warehouse opposite Gillian Anderson playing Ivor in Kfir Yefets hit production of “The Doll’s House” in 2009, and then in 2010 he then went on to take the role of Bert’ in the sell out, smash hit Howard Davies production of “All My Sons” opposite Zoe Wanamaker and David Suchet at The Apollo, Shaftesbury Avenue.

This would most likely have made him 10 during the filming of [Thor](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0800369/?ref_=nv_sr_2) (considering a 2011 release date ... filming most likely occurred in 2010). I didn't find an entire bio which included his date of birth.